# Showing result in tabhost on android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tabhost

[image: Emulator's image]

The above image is just adding two values and displaying the result on the below textview.
But i need to show that answer on the first tab(ie.Tab_1) of tabhost on next screen.
How to do this?

**.java class**

```
 public class Demo_webserviceActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
   private static String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

   Button btnFar;
   EditText txtFar;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);

   txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);

   btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
   public void onClick(View v)
   {

       String b;

     //Initialize soap request + add parameters
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

     //Use this to add parameters
     request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

     //Declare the version of the SOAP request
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     envelope.dotNet = true;

     try 
     {
         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

         //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

         // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

         SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

         if(result != null)
         {
          //Get the first property and change the label text

            b = result.toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
            i.putExtra("gotonextpage", b.toString());
            startActivity(i);
          }

         else
         {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
   });
   }
}
```

*NOTE* : This source is actually consuming a webservice from android and showing the result by SOAP method

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Fragment` or `ActivityGroup` can be of your help.

Comment: Have you ever tried any code before?

Comment: Hi-SpK, yes i've tried some,but its not showing the result on tabhost,just showing only on single page

Comment: will i send u my sources by editting my question?

Comment: Sure. That would be very nice

Comment: please visit my question again,i've updated my question.Please find me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Shared preferences to store values, then you can access it in any activity of your project:

follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)